# How do i translate multiple strings from an object after getting object from an http request and then store that object with translated strings

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am getting an object from an http request. I am storing that object by another http request using put method. I want to translate some strings in that object to a different language using google translate api before storing that object. How can i achieve that.

service.ts

> ```
>     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
> import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
> import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
>
> import { BaseApi } from '../../../../laas/base-api.service';
> import { ApplicantService } from '../../../../laas/applicant.service';
> import { environment as ENV } from '../../../../../environments/environment'
>
> @Injectable()
> export class NregaService {
>
>   private applicantId: string;
>   private baseUrl: string;
>
>   constructor(
>     private http: HttpClient,
>     private api: BaseApi,
>     private applicant: ApplicantService
>   ) {
>     this.applicantId = applicant.getApplicantID()
>     this.baseUrl = `/applicants/${this.applicantId}/id/nrega`;
>
>   }
>
>   get() {
>     return this.api.newGet(this.baseUrl);
>   }
>
>   save(type, data) {
>     return this.api.put(this.baseUrl, { type: type, data: data });
>   }
>
>   translate(q) {
>     const translateUrl = ENV.googleAddress.translateUrl;
>     const apiKey = ENV.googleAddress.apiKey;
>     const target = 'en';
>     const model = 'base';
>     return this.http.post(`${translateUrl}${apiKey}`, { q, target, model }).map(res => {
>       const value = res['data'].translations[0];
>       console.log(`Translated ${q}:`, value);
>       return value.translatedText;
>     });
>   }
>
>   verify(id) {
>     return this.api.post('nrega', { jobcardid: id }).map(result => {
>       if (typeof result === typeof '') {
>         throw result;
>       }
>
>       const incomes = [];
>       if (result.incomeDetail) {
>         result.incomeDetail
>           .sort((a, b) => a.year <= b.year ? -1 : 1)
>           .forEach(income => incomes.push({ income: income['income(Rs.)'], year: income.year }));
>       }
>
>       const details = [];
>       if (result.applicantDetail) {
>         result.applicantDetail.forEach(detail => details.push({
>           name: detail.name,
>           gender: detail.gender[0].toLowerCase(),
>           age: detail.age,
>           bankOrPostOffice: detail.bankorpostoffice,
>           aadhaarNo: detail.aadhaarNo,
>           accountNo: detail.accountNo
>         }));
>       }
>
>       const data = {
>         jobCardId: result.jobcardno,
>         regDate: result.dateOfRegistration,
>         photo: result.photoImageUrl,
>         voterId: result.voterId,
>         fatherOrHusband: result.nameOfFatherOrHusband,
>         family: {
>           ids: [result.familyId1, result.familyId],
>           members: details,
>           head: result.nameOfHead,
>           isBpl: result.bplFamily.toLowerCase() === 'yes' ? true : false,
>           bplId: result.bplFamilyId,
>         },
>         address: {
>           full: result.address,
>           village: result.village,
>           district: result.district,
>           panchayat: result.panchayat,
>           block: result.block
>         },
>         category: result.category,
>         incomes: incomes,
>       };
>       console.log('NREGA: ', data);
>
>       return data;
>     });
>   }
>
> }
> ```

If i use translate method to translate strings in service itself then i get error maybe because i did not use .subscribe method (which i am using in component where i am calling verify() method from service. Is it possible to convert multiple string in service itself before even returning the data to component?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the Rxjs **map** operator.

First of all, import this operator in your service.ts file.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Then, if I got your point, you want to translate some strings when your component calls the get method, after the data has been received from the server but before the method has sent the data back to the component.

> *component > service.get() > http request > data received from server > **translate** > data sent to the component*

If I am correct, the only thing you have to do is to use the map operator :

```
get() {
  return this.api.newGet(this.baseUrl)
    .map(data => this.translate(data));
}
```

Let's imagine a *SourceData* type and a *ModifiedData* types. The map operator will let you return an `Observable<ModifiedData>` instead of the `Observable<SourceData>` you used to send back. Look at the documentation [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) for a better explanation.

Note that you could also do the translation when your save method is called.

```
save(type, data) {
  data = this.translate(data)
  return this.api.put(this.baseUrl, { type: type, data: data });
}
```